# MediaRecorderAPI - Autorecord

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am currently trying to simulate audio autorecording. User speaks, and after he stops then audio should be submitted to the backend.
I already have a sample script that submits audio with start and stop click functions.

I'm trying to get sometype of value such as Amplitude, Volume or maybe a Threshold but I'm not sure if MediaRecorder supports this or if I need to look at Web Audio API or other solutions.

Can I achieve this with MediaRecorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the audio analysis of the mic input, the following example shows you how to take the audio captured by the mic, create an analyzer with `createAnalyser` method of the `webkitAudioContext`, connect the stream to the analyzer and calculate the FFT of the specified size, in order to calculate pitch and display the output sound wave.

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext = null;
var isPlaying = false;
var sourceNode = null;
var analyser = null;
var theBuffer = null;
var audioCtx = null;
var mediaStreamSource = null;
var rafID = null;
var j = 0;
var waveCanvas = null;

window.onload = function() {
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
    audioCtx = document.getElementById( "waveform" );
    canvasCtx = audioCtx.getContext("2d");
};
function getUserMedia(dictionary, callback) {
    try {
        navigator.getUserMedia = 
            navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        navigator.getUserMedia(dictionary, callback, error);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('getUserMedia threw exception :' + e);
    }
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    // Connect it to the destination.
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;
    mediaStreamSource.connect( analyser );
    updatePitch();
}
function toggleLiveInput() 
{
    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCtx.width, audioCtx.height);
    canvasCtx.beginPath();
    j = 0;
    buflen = 1024;
    buf = new Float32Array( buflen );
    document.getElementById('toggleLiveInput').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('toggleLiveInputStop').disabled = false;
    if (isPlaying) {
        //stop playing and return
        sourceNode.stop( 0 );
        sourceNode = null;
        //analyser = null;
        isPlaying = false;
        if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
            window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame;
        window.cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
    }
    getUserMedia(
        {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            },
        }, gotStream);
}
function stop()
{
    document.getElementById('toggleLiveInput').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('toggleLiveInputStop').disabled = true;
    //waveCanvas.closePath();
    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame;
    window.cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
    return "start";
}
function updatePitch() 
{
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(buf);
    canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "red";
    for (var i=0;i<2;i+=2) 
    {
        x = j*5;
        if(audioCtx.width < x)
        {
            x = audioCtx.width - 5;     
            previousImage = canvasCtx.getImageData(5, 0, audioCtx.width, audioCtx.height);
            canvasCtx.putImageData(previousImage, 0, 0);
            canvasCtx.beginPath();
            canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
            canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "red";
            prex = prex - 5;
            canvasCtx.lineTo(prex,prey);
            prex = x;
            prey = 128+(buf[i]*128);
            canvasCtx.lineTo(x,128+(buf[i]*128));
            canvasCtx.stroke();

        }
        else
        {
            prex = x;
            prey = 128+(buf[i]*128);
            canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
            canvasCtx.lineTo(x,128+(buf[i]*128));
            canvasCtx.stroke();
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updatePitch );
}
function error() {
    console.error(new Error('error while generating audio'));
}
```

Try the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ta82q7e/).
Example adapted from [pitch-liveinput](https://github.com/agiratech/picth-liveinput).